# problema con los caracteres

Tags: c, caracteres

alguien sabe por que cuando pongo una letra distinta de "r" en la variable color y la variable activacion en 1 me pone eliminado?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int numero;
    int color;
    int activacion;compartenos

    scanf("%d", &numero);
    scanf(" %c", &color);
    scanf("%d", &activacion);

    if ((color = "r") && activacion == 1){
        printf("Jugador %d ELIMINADO", numero);

    }else if((color = "r") && activacion == 0){
        printf("Jugador %d CONTINUAR", numero);

    }else  {
        printf("Jugador %d CONTINUAR", numero);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto `color = "r"` es asignar y esto `color == "r"` es comparar

Comment: al hacer ese cambio ponga lo que ponga tanto en la variable color como en la variable activacion me sale el CONTINUAR, alguna idea de por que?

Comment: Como comenta @Christian, estas asignando. Ademas, esa no es la forma correcta de comparar cadenas en C, tienes que usar [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO en Español, tienes tres problemas con tú código:

1. Si vas a recibir un `char`, como lo hace en `scanf(" %c", &color)` (el `%c` indica que vas a interpretar el buffer como un `char`) debes de guardar su contenido en una variable de este tipo. En tu código la variable color es un `int`, eso no es congruente.
2. No confundas el operador de asignación `=` con el operador de equidad/comparación `==`.
3. Cuando haces `"r"` estas haciendo referencia a una `string` y como lo dice [Pablochaches](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/153685/pablochaches) no puedes usar el operador `==` para comparar una string en C. En tu caso estás comparando un `char` y para hacer referencia a un valor de este tipo se utilizan apóstrofes, es decir, `'r'`.

Tomando todo esto en cuenta, tú código podría verse así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

  int numero;
  char color;
  int activacion;

  scanf ("%d", &numero);
  scanf (" %c", &color);
  scanf ("%d", &activacion);

  if ((color == 'r') && activacion == 1)
    {
      printf ("Jugador %d ELIMINADO", numero);

    }
  else if ((color == 'r') && activacion == 0)
    {
      printf ("Jugador %d CONTINUAR", numero);

    }
  else
    {
      printf ("Jugador %d CONTINUAR", numero);
    }

  return 0;
}
```